# How to prevent div elements from moving when the browser gets resized?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a website for a school work, but when I resize the screen and make it a little wider, the `div` elements are getting out of their place.

How can I prevent this?

**most of the divs are:**

```
.menu {
    padding-top:120px;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    font-size:28pt;
    font-weight:Bolder; 
}
```

**My html:**

```
<body id="BODY" class="BDNL" onResize="MOSTRA()"> 
  <div id="resizing" class="">
    <div id="intro" class="divintro">
      <p id="p" class="comeco">Trabalho Interdisciplinar Orientado:</p>
      <p id="texto" class="txtcomum">
        Trabalho no qual um grupo deve elaborar um site que <br />
        relacione todas as matérias técnicas estudadas.
      </p>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div id="menu" class="menu">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="index.html"><label>RECO</label></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href=""><label>LOCO</label></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href=""><label> LP1</label></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href=""><label> LP2</label></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href=""><label> INFO</label></a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the HTML code?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did my answer not help you a tiny bit? Took me some time to compile it for you, you might want to consider coming back at your questions and select accepted answers or the like in the future, you won't get full on answers for long if you don't react to answers.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) and [width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) properties of CSS.

---

Okay. Your HTML looks quite messy.
First of all, please start indending your code for the sake of your own eyes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
    </head>
    <body class="BDNL" onResize="MOSTRA()">
        <div id="resizing">
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="index.html">RECO</a>|
                <a href="other.html">LOCO</a>|
                [--]
            </div>
            <div id="intro">
                <p>
                    <h1>Trabalho Interdisciplinar Orientado</h1>
                    [..]
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the minimal HTML-source you need to achieve the structure you desire.
Why exactly are you using `position:absolute;` on the `.menu`, I guess you want it to be positioned on top of the actual content?
I moved the `.menu` above the `#intro` container.

Use the following CSS to achieve the result you may want:

```
.menu {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0; /* bottom margin 30px */
}

.menu a {
    margin: 0 20px; /* left, right margin 20px; top, bottom 0 */
}
```

Also

- please decide wether you want to use classes or IDs on your elements, in most cases you won't need both,
- get rid of redundant classes and IDs (`<p class="p">` or `<p id="p">` do *not* make sense),
- use the propper html elements for your content. Use `<h1>` - .. tags for headlines instead of differently styled paragraphs.
- Make yourself familiar with [CSS Margins](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) and get rid of multiple `&nbsp;`.

As mentioned in your other question, you might want to give your elements (for example .menu) a fixed (min-)width which prevents the element from getting too narrow:

```
.menu {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```